# django naturaltime returning the same result

Tags: python, django, django-admin

```
In my model i have a fields like :
```

time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

```
In view page i am getting the value like in this format :
```

2020-03-15T11:07:07.089Z

```
I am getting the date time in this format.
```

{{ result.time|naturaltime }}

but its not working it returning me the same date whick is comming from the data base

Comment: Any suggestion any one have  ??? a

Comment: Your question is not clear, what exactly you try to do. Add more details and we will help you :3

Comment: @M3duZa My question is that i am getting date in this format : 2020-03-15T11:07:07.089Z    How can i convert this in mar 15,2020 ,07:07 A.M

Comment: Instead of `auto_now_add`, can you try `auto_now`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DateField` instead of `DateTimeField`. 
Like :
`time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)` here is a link for django fields(for more clarity) : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/